# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0

Tags: django

Please help, when I run server compilator get me to mistake - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0: invalid continuation byte

I'm using python 3.7

Comment: could you provide more information.  it'd be pretty lucky for someone to read this and understand what you're talking about.

Comment: what is a server compilator?

Comment: you should provide the stack trace from your error and a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you tried to read a file using utf-8, but inside that file are characters not matching utf-8 encoding mode.
Probably it was not a txt file but an other file type.
The simply solution is to read that file as binary file and then convert to a string.Like in the code below:

```
    f1=open(your_file_path,'rb')
    filecontent=f1.read()
    filecontent=str(filecontent)
```

Now you can check e.g. if the file contains a substring or not.